Google Actions account linking for different Env
I have a live Google action that is working fine with my prod env with my fulfillment URL, Authorization URL and token URL pointing to my Prod server. I have made some changes on my backend and want to test the same in Dev Env before moving to Prod.
The fulfillment URL, Authorization URL, and token URL are different because of separate Dev env. I tried changing this URL, pointing to my dev env, and made an alpha release(I have added alpha users as well).
How do I test this cause in my Google Home the action that is displayed is still old?
cause to log in through my app there is a deep link that takes me to the old Authorization URL even after changing and pointing to my Dev.
I am still new to this and trying to understand. Please point out if I'm doing something wrong.

Google tries to use to the endpoints specified in the Actions On Google console. You should ensure that the endpoints are updated and are the correct ones for proper implementation.
